# Web Request using UploadValuesAsync not reaching web api action

Tags: api, web

I have created the following mvc web api controller action

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Model model)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);

        return response;
    }
```

and calling it from the following web request all works fine

var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadValues(uri, "POST", valuesToPost);

Then, if I try to use UploadValuesAsync instead of UploadValues the web api action is never reached.
Any ideas? Do I have to declare the web api action as an async action? I tryed that but didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts got it working by modifying the api like this:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(Model model)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);

        await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());

        return response;
    }
```

Hope it can help someone else.